# Unused classes not packaged in a Maven multi-module project

Tags: java, maven

I'm using Maven 3.6.2 with a multi-module Java project. The `example` module depends on the `core` module, so I have a dependency in the `example` module's POM like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The issue is that not all of the classes from the `core` module are being packaged into the `example` jar when I run `mvn clean install`. Only the classes that are used in the `example` project are being packaged. I need all classes packaged for a later process.

I'm using the `maven-shade-plugin` with this configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I include all classes from the `core` module in the `example` jar without having to use them in the `example` jar?

Comment: Looks like `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` is the culprit. Does it do what you want if you set that to false?

Comment: I walked away from this a bit and came to the same conclusion when I came back to it. It makes so much sense now, but I must have been staring at it for too long! Thanks for your help, @Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the `minimizeJar` parameter. According to https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#minimizeJar:

> When true, dependencies will be stripped down on the class level to
> only the transitive hull required for the artifact.

I removed that parameter and it worked as expected.